# Trying to use dictionary of dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have an issue when I execute this code:

```
def create_binary_nw(row):
    if row['Net_withdrawal'] <=0:
        return 0
    else:
        return 1

# a class 
class create_storages:

    def __init__(self,file1,file2):
        self.file1 = file1
        self.file2 = file2

    def open_storages(self):
        wb = load_workbook(self.file1)#load the file to a workbook
        ws = wb.sheetnames # get all the names of Excel sheets in order to construct a dictionary
        storages = {}# a dictionary
        storages = pd.read_excel(self.file1, sheet_name = None)# adding the dictionary element
        return [storages, ws]



    def complete_storages(self):
        [storages,ws] = self.open_storages()
        for i in range(len(ws)):    
            NW = storages[ws[i]]['withdrawal']-storages[ws[i]]['injection']
            storages[ws[i]].insert(7, "Net_withdrawal",NW, True)#adding the column NW NO PROBLEM
            storages[ws[i]]['Net_withdrawal_binary']= storages[ws[i]].apply(create_binary_nw(storages[ws[i]]),axis=1)#THE PROBLEM IS HERE!!!

    enter code here

     # execution
     class_storage = create_storages('storage_data.xlsx','price_data.csv')
     #[storage1,ws1] = class_storage.open_storages()
     class_storage.complete_storages()
```

The error I get is :

```
> ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, 
a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

I think the error comes from my function create_binary when i apply it on storages[ws[i]] which is a dictionary of dataframe (storages is a dictionary and storages[ws[i]] is a dataframe which has a column named 'Net_withdrawal' which is a column of float numbers)

Thanks for any answers

Answer (score 0):

What the error message is telling you, is that if you want to compare an array of values with whether they are less than 0 (`<=0`) you can do  `a.any()`(any is less than 0) or `a.all()` (all less than 0).
If you want a simpler example see this:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([1,1,0])
if a > 0: # fails here, array can't be compared with a single value
  print("yay")
```

For the actual error in this case, I suspect the mistake is in the `apply` call.

```
storages[ws[i]]['Net_withdrawal_binary']= storages[ws[i]].apply(create_binary_nw(storages[ws[i]]),axis=1)#THE PROBLEM IS HERE!!!
```

should probably be

```
storages[ws[i]]['Net_withdrawal_binary']= storages[ws[i]].apply(lambda a: create_binary_nw(a),axis=1)
```

because otherwise `storages[ws[i]]['Net_withdrawal']` is an array and not a single value and can't be compared with 0 (`<=0`) in `create_binary_nw`.

Here is more information on the `apply` function: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html

Comment: ok thank's for your answer.Indeed storages[ws[i]]['Net_withdrawal] is a colomn of a dataframe and not a number